# Move HTML out from these enclosing CDATA tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating HTML using JS templating engine (by John Resig). However the output generated is enclosed within

```
<!--  <![CDATA[            ......            ]]>   //-->
```

Is there any simpler way to move the HTML out from these enclosing CDATA tags other than using JS string processing methods ?

Comment: You might want to look at some of the more recently-developed template systems, like [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com), [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT), etc. [And here's a handy tool.](http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/)

Comment: I dont know if these libraries work smoothly with xhtml(required for my case).. & is it really worth adding another library to the project when simply adding this small script by Resig (seemingly) works fine!?

Comment: There's nothing inherent about any JavaScript template engine I know of that has anything to do with XHTML compatibility. That's pretty much up to what you code into your templates. Some of those libraries (particularly doT) are really small.

Comment: Oh also some (again, esp. doT) are almost certainly *much* faster. Plus you can run some of these at *build* time, and some have no need for any other client-side framework - they produce pure, standalone JavaScript.

Comment: I think you maybe need to post more context - that code (ejohn's template engine) doesn't generate that stuff; it must be coming from something else.  Where are you seeing that CDATA wrapper?  Are you sure a tool isn't synthetically showing it to you?

Comment: @Pointy: Seeing that through `console.log()`.  Actually, CDATA tags(but not commented) were put by myself in order to make the template inside script tags compatible on xhtml pages. I just want to remove those CDATA tags.

Comment: Well when you access the contents of the `<script>` tag programmatically (from JavaScript) after the page is loaded and the DOM built, do you still see the CDATA tags? That doesn't make sense.